# Pass data from callback to React component?

Tags: javascript, callback, reactjs

I'm rendering a react component that needs data that returns asynchronously. How should I pass this to the react component when it returns from the callback?

currently in render function:

```
var dataToReturn; 
asynchCall(args, function(err, results) {
  dataToReturn = results;
})

return (
    <MyComponent data={dataToReturn} />
)
```

This of course is not working out because the data has not returned yet. If I move the render into the callback, that seems like a bad programming pattern. Is there anything in the React API meant for this use case?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, like @Fouad said:

```
var NewComponent = React.createClass({ 
    componentDidMount: function() {
       asynchCall(args, function(err, results) {
          this.setState({data: results});
       }.bind(this));
    },

    return (
        <MyComponent data={this.state.data} />
    )
});
```

Also, check out documentation page [Load Initial Data via AJAX](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html)

Comment: But to be clear, do this in componentDidMount, and bind the callback so this.setState doesn't mean window.setState.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand yeah, you are right, thank you. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of local variables you should use `this.state` & `this.setState` which will trigger a re-render. Check out this link on fetching from the server http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#fetching-from-the-server